# Update date in MySQL to contain leading zeros

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a column `col1` in table `tab1` that has following mixed format dates:

```
2015-03-03
2015-02-03
2017-3-6
2015-03-04
2017-11-6
```

What would be a good MySQL query to update this column to something more consistent, so all dates contain leading zeros

Comment: The answer is DON'T have a column like this. Force consistency from the outset!

Comment: Best way is to store dates as date type not as formated string

Comment: A date doesn't *store* leading zeroes.  You can format your date values however you like when you output them to the user, but you store them as date values.

Comment: Ah I should mention those are strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be storing these as a date field to begin with
but anyway here's your query

```
UPDATE `tab1` SET `col1` = DATE(`col1`);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'm aware that at some point I'll need to convert it to date format but I needed temporary solution with string and yours was perfect answer for that.

Comment: I didn't think this would work (hence my answer below) +1

Comment: This does not work with dates stored in spanish format

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, to ward off evil spirits as well at that downvoter who has hit me like 6 times today, you should be storing your dates as...dates, and not as text.  That being said, if you have a lot of text data in this format, you can fairly easily convert it to a date by using MySQL's string functions.  The month and day fields, which may be either one or two digits, will need to be left-padded with a zero.  Then, use `STR_TO_DATE` with the appropriate format mask to bring the standardized date text to a bona-fide date.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 1),
                    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', 2), '-', -1), 2, '0'),
                    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '-', -1), 2, '0')), '%Y%m%d') AS new_date
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want to update a new column in your table, you can reuse the above logic almost verbatim, just do an `UPDATE` instead of a `SELECT`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester